# Low whir when moving on my motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, noise, suzuki

So I recently needed to replace the tube in the back tire on my Suzuki GS 450.

Now I'm getting a low whir sound when moving, even if I kill the engine and coast. As far as I can tell it is coming from directly under me. I'm thinking that it's likely just the chain being a bit too tight, but is there anything else I should look for?

I'm also needing to press the clutch a bit harder when starting to avoid lurching forward, if it is related.

Answer (score 2):

**Perhaps you over-tightened your chain**

Check to see if there is slack in your chain.  You will want a centimeter to 1.5 centimeters of slack.

An over-tightened chain will lead to the exact sound you are describing.  It also is hard on your transmission secondary shaft as well as your sprockets and chain.

If you hit a large bump and your swingarm has excessive movement during this condition you can stretch your chain and force a replacement.  It will begin to 'hop' where part of the chain is stretched and part is not.

When you adjust your chain, be sure your rear wheel is in the air so you can spin it in neutral and check various points to ensure you build your 1cm of slack into the tightest area of the chain.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad on the verification. I'm definately too tight.  What about the extra pul on the clutch l need when starting?

Comment: The clutch is separate mechanism an issue.  Possibly just Lubking it with a dry lubricant.  Try asking a separate question and I'll list some causes.